# How is a function classified when it returns the same value on successive calls?

Tags: function, math

I'm looking for a term that describes this property:

> **For any** `x` **in the domain of function** `f`**,** `f(x) == f(f(x))`

For example, `mod` has that property:

```
5 % 2 = 1
5 % 2 % 2 % 2 % 2 % 2 = 1
```

But percent-encoding and -decoding do not:

```
encode('fifty%') = 'fifty%25'
encode(encode('fifty%')) = 'fifty%2525'

decode('%252f') = '%2f'
decode(decode('%252f')) = '/'
```

Comment: This question might be better suited to http://math.stackexchange.com/, since it's about functions in the theoretical sense, not programming *per se*.

Comment: I considered it, but the examples that kept coming out of my brain were programming-oriented, and I *knew* that this community would rise to the challenge.

Comment: For reference, Wikipedia mentions that in programming the term is sometimes used slightly differently:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Computer_science_meaning

Comment: @JKillian eat! Turns out "nullipotence" is a thing too.

Comment: "Idempotence" is a term mostly used (in the computing arena) to refer to network services where a request has the same effect whether it's repeated once or multiple times.  Eg, if the first request adds a record to a database, subsequent identical requests will leave the DB unchanged.  This is the basis of the [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) "meta-architecture" for web services.

Comment: woops.  I meant @JKillian neat, not eat!

Comment: @HotLicks, idempotence is used more generally than just network services.  Apparently everything from databases to compilers care about that word/idea.  Also, REST has more than one "basis" ([Roy Fielding calls them architectural constraints](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm), not bases).  Idempotence is emergent from the constraints of statelessness and uniform access, but the term does not actually appear in Roy Fielding's dissertation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Idempotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).

Shortest answer I've ever written — I had to add this sentence to meet SO's minimum post length.  :-)

Comment: It could (and should) be *usefully* longer.

Comment: @user2864740, the answer pretty succinctly addresses my problem.  What do you suggest?

Comment: @user2864740: What more is there to say?

Comment: I (although probably biased) think this answers the question quite well enough. :)

Comment: Why not remove that noisy sentence with a definition?  No need to brag about posting a super-short answer.

Comment: Because kdbanman already defined it clearly and succinctly in the question - there's no point in being redundant. Sheesh, if an answer gives the needed information, it's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

The term your looking for is "Idempotence."

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence

Comment: So, what does this mean? Without having to click a link?

Comment: Link-only answers are still sloppy.